# Start a service from a service

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget that is updated by a service. The service also sets an OnClick event for an `ImageButton` that is in the widget layout. The way I do this is by setting a PendingIntent that is supposed to open the service.

However, when I click the refresh button, nothing happens.

```
public void setRefreshButton(Context context, RemoteViews views) {
    Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingRefreshIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, widgetUpdateIntent, 0);
    }
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_refresh,
            pendingRefreshIntent);
}
```

I have a log at the first line of `onStart()` of my service, but that doesn't even show up in LogCat. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PendingIntent` attempts to starts an `Activity`, not a `Service`. Try with `PendingIntent.getService`.